# How to unzip xml file using PHP

Tags: php, xml, zip, xmldom

I have a zipped `XML` file on my `PHP` system.

How do I unzip it to load it into `XMLDOM`?

I only have one `XML` file per `zip` archive.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the php classes [ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php) and [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) i.e.:

```
<?php
//set the correct xml headers to output to browser
header("Content-type: text/xml");
$zipFile = "file.zip";
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open($zipFile))
{
    //get the xml filename inside the zip
    $xmlFile =  $zip->getNameIndex(0); //you only  have 1 xml file iside of the zip
    $zip->close();
    //read the xml file inside the zip without extracting it to disk (memory)
    $xml = file_get_contents("zip://$zipFile#$xmlFile");
    //create a new document
    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', "UTF-8");
    //load teh xml file
    $dom->loadXML($xml);
    //Here you can  manipulate the XML dom , add, remove nodes, etc.
    //save and echo the XML
    echo $dom->saveXML();
} else {
    echo 'zip open failed failed';
}
```

---

Notes:

1. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
2. I've tested the code with [this xml file](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml) and it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for answer. However, do I need to extract to disk? I guess it will be faster if not extracting to disk and then read from disk?

Comment: Hmm, if I have to read the XML file from disk after unzipping it, it has no point to zip it... Isnt there any way to unzip without writing to and then reading from the file system? Thanks again.

Comment: The question is straight forward and easy to understand. The answer will probably involve using gzip instead of zip if zip can only be extracted to disk.

Comment: Your question wasn't that clear but I managed to understand you ;) Check my updated answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @darshanparab Glad to know that. GL.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);

echo "Start Time - " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";

//MySQL connection
//$link = mysql_connect('HOST', 'userbane', 'password')or die("Dtabase Not connected.");
$link = mysql_connect('HOST', 'userbane', 'password')or die("Dtabase Not connected.");
mysql_select_db("unified", $link);

//FTP connection
$ftp_server = "xx.xx.xxxx";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");

$epgVersion = FALSE;

if (ftp_login($ftp_conn, 'usename', 'password')) {

    $date = date('Y-m-d');

    //Processing ZIP Files
    echo "Processing ZIP Files\n";
    $contents = ftp_nlist($ftp_conn, "-t *.zip");

    if (count($contents) > 0) {

        $epgVersion = TRUE;

        foreach ($contents as $content) {
            $file_name = trim($content);

            $zipDirectory = "/home/customscript/epg/epg_zip_data/$date";

            if (!is_dir($zipDirectory)) {
                mkdir($zipDirectory);
            }

            $zipTmpDirectory = "/home/customscript/epg/epg_zip_tmp";

            if (!is_dir($zipTmpDirectory)) {
                mkdir($zipTmpDirectory);
            }

            $local_file = $zipDirectory . "/" . $file_name;
            // try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
            if (ftp_get($ftp_conn, $local_file, $file_name, FTP_BINARY)) {
                echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";

                //Posting to Appinventiv
                postToAppinventiv($local_file);
        //continue;

                $zip = new ZipArchive;  //unzip file
                if ($zip->open($local_file) === TRUE) {  //extract contents to /data/ folder
                    $zip->extractTo($zipTmpDirectory . '/');
                    $zip->close();            //close the archive

                    $files = glob($zipTmpDirectory . "/" . "*.xml");

                    if (is_array($files)) {

                        foreach ($files as $filename) {

                            $fileParseStatus = parseXmlFile($filename, 1);
                            if ($fileParseStatus) {
                                echo "File '$filename' has been successfully processed.\n";
                                if (unlink($filename)) {
                                    echo "File '$filename' deleted successfully.\n";
                                } else {
                                    echo "File '$filename' deleted Failed.\n";
                                }
                            } else {
                                echo "Unable to open '$filename' XML file.\n";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //unlink($local_file);
                } else {
                    echo "Failed to open the archive!\n";
                }
            } else {
                echo "There was a problem\n";
            }

            if (ftp_delete($ftp_conn, $file_name)) {
                echo "$file_name deleted from ftp successfully\n";
            } else {
                echo "$file_name could not be deleted from ftp\n";
            }
        }
        echo "Processing of ZIP Files are done.\n";
    } else {
        echo "No zip file to process.\n";
    }

    //Processing XML Files
    echo "Processing XML Files\n";
    $contents = ftp_nlist($ftp_conn, "-t *.xml");

    if (count($contents) > 0) {

        $epgVersion = TRUE;

        foreach ($contents as $content) {
            $file_name = trim($content);

            $xmlDirectory = "/home/customscript/epg/epg_xml_data/$date";

            if (!is_dir($xmlDirectory)) {
                mkdir($xmlDirectory);
            }

            $xmlTmpDirectory = "/home/customscript/epg/epg_xml_tmp";

            if (!is_dir($xmlTmpDirectory)) {
                mkdir($xmlTmpDirectory);
            }

            $local_file = $xmlDirectory . "/" . $file_name;
            // try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
            if (ftp_get($ftp_conn, $local_file, $file_name, FTP_BINARY)) {
                echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";

                //Posting to Appinventiv
                postToAppinventiv($local_file);

                copy($xmlDirectory . "/" . $file_name, $xmlTmpDirectory . "/" . $file_name);

                $fileParseStatus = parseXmlFile($xmlTmpDirectory . "/" . $file_name, 2);
                if ($fileParseStatus) {
                    echo "File '$file_name' has been successfully processed.\n";
                    if (unlink($xmlTmpDirectory . "/" . $file_name)) {
                        echo "File '$file_name' deleted successfully.\n";
                    } else {
                        echo "File '$file_name' deleted Failed.\n";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "Unable to open '$file_name' XML file.\n";
                }
            } else {
                echo "There was a problem\n";
            }

            if (ftp_delete($ftp_conn, $file_name)) {
                echo "$file_name deleted from ftp successfully\n";
            } else {
                echo "$file_name could not be deleted from ftp\n";
            }
        }
        echo "Processing of XML Files are done.\n";
    } else {
        echo "No xml file to process.\n";
    }
} else {
    echo "Unable to connect with the FTP server.\n";
}

ftp_close($ftp_conn);

if ($epgVersion) {

    $epgUpdateQuery = "UPDATE version set EPG_VERSION=EPG_VERSION+1";
    $epgUpdateQueryStatus = mysql_query($epgUpdateQuery, $link);
    if ($epgUpdateQueryStatus) {
        echo "EPG version updated successfully.\n";
    } else {
        echo "EPG version update query failed.\n";
    }
}

echo "End Time - " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";

function parseXmlFile($filename, $queryType) {
    $link = $GLOBALS['link'];

    $file_get = file_get_contents($filename);
    if ($file_get) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($file_get);
        $chan_category = mysql_escape_string(trim($xml->channel->category));
        $channel_name = mysql_escape_string(trim($xml->channel->{'display-name'}));
        $service_id = mysql_escape_string(trim($xml->channel->serviceid));
        $channel_logo = mysql_escape_string(trim($xml->channel->ChannelLogo));
        $programme = $xml->programme;

        $programme_date = trim($xml->programme->attributes()->start);  // delete data above current date
        $expld_date = explode(" ", $programme_date);
        $s_curdate = trim($expld_date[0]);
        $start_curtime_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($s_curdate));

        if ($queryType == 1) {
            $deleteType = ">=";
        } else if ($queryType == 2) {
            $deleteType = "=";
        }

        $sql_del = "DELETE FROM `Program_Details` WHERE Service_Id = '$service_id' and date(`Start_Time`) $deleteType '$start_curtime_date'";
        mysql_query($sql_del, $link);
        //echo $sql_del . PHP_EOL;

        $i = 0;
        $insert_programs_sql = array();
        foreach ($programme as $prog) {
            $cast = $prog->cast;
            $actors = '';
            $directors = '';
            $producers = '';
            if ($cast) {
                foreach ($cast as $c) {
                    $actor_arr = array();
                    foreach ($c->actor as $t) {
                        $actor_arr[] = (string) mysql_escape_string(trim($t));
                    }
                    $actors = implode(',', $actor_arr);
                    $directors = mysql_escape_string(trim($c->director));
                    $producers = mysql_escape_string(trim($c->producer));
                }
            }
            $start = (string) trim($prog->attributes()->start);
            $stop = (string) trim($prog->attributes()->stop);

            $expld_sdate = explode(" ", $start);
            $s_date = trim($expld_sdate[0]);
            $start_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($s_date));


            $expld_edate = explode(" ", $stop);
            $e_date = trim($expld_edate[0]);
            $end_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($e_date));

            // Create two new DateTime-objects...
            $date1 = new DateTime($start);
            $date2 = new DateTime($stop);

            // The diff-methods returns a new DateInterval-object...
            $diff = $date2->diff($date1);

            // Call the format method on the DateInterval-object
            $hour = $diff->format('%h');
            $min = $diff->format('%i');
            $duration = ($hour * 60) + $min;

            $prod_id = mysql_escape_string(trim($prog->programmeid));
            $title = mysql_escape_string(trim($prog->title));
            $desc = mysql_escape_string(trim($prog->desc));
            $category = mysql_escape_string(trim($prog->category));
            $subcat = mysql_escape_string(trim($prog->{'sub-category'}));
            $VideoUrl = mysql_escape_string(trim($prog->ProgrammeVideoUrl));
            $ImageUrl = mysql_escape_string(trim($prog->ImageUrl));
            $insert_programs_sql[] = "('$service_id','$channel_name','$prod_id','$title','$desc','$category','$subcat','$ImageUrl','$VideoUrl','$start_time','$end_time','$chan_category','$channel_logo','$actors','$directors','$producers','$duration')";
            $i++;
            if ($i === 2000) {
                $sql_prog = "INSERT INTO `Program_Details`(`Service_Id`,`Service_Name`, `Program_Id`, `Title`, `Description`, `Category`, `sub_categories`, `image_urls`, `video_urls`, `Start_Time`,`end_time`,`channel_categories`,`channel_logos`,actors,directors,producers,Duration) VALUES " . implode(',', $insert_programs_sql);

                $epg_programs_insert_query_status = mysql_query($sql_prog, $link);
                if (!$epg_programs_insert_query_status) {
                    die(mysql_errno($link));
                }
                $i = 0;
                $insert_programs_sql = array();
            }
        }

        if (count($insert_programs_sql) > 0) {
            $sql_prog = "INSERT INTO `Program_Details`(`Service_Id`,`Service_Name`, `Program_Id`, `Title`, `Description`, `Category`, `sub_categories`, `image_urls`, `video_urls`, `Start_Time`,`end_time`,`channel_categories`,`channel_logos`,actors,directors,producers,Duration) VALUES " . implode(',', $insert_programs_sql);

            $epg_programs_insert_query_status = mysql_query($sql_prog, $link);
            if (!$epg_programs_insert_query_status) {
                die(mysql_errno($link));
            }
        }

        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

function postToAppinventiv($file) {
    $url = "http://172.31.xx.xxx/admin/epgzip";
    //$file_name_with_full_path = realpath("./$file");
    //$post = array('epg_zip' => new CurlFile($file));
    $post = array('epg_zip' => '@' . $file);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300); //timeout in seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'abvjjlk: xxxxxxxxxxx',
        'authorization: xxxxxxxxxxx'
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    //curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($info['http_code'] == 200) {
        logging("INFO", $file . ":" . $result);
        return $result;
    } else {
        logging("ERROR", $result);
        return FALSE;
    }
}

function logging($type, $message) {
    $logFileName = '/home/customscript/epg/logs/' . date('Y-m-d') . ".log";

    $message = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '|' . $type . '|' . $message . PHP_EOL;
    error_log($message, 3, $logFileName);
}
```

Comment: Impressive :-) Thanks a lot.